# Keyword-Label-Value style configuration file parsing library for C

Tags: c, parsing, configuration-files

Does a configuration parsing library exist already that will read the following style of file:

`Keyword Label Value;`

With nesting by `{ }` replacing Values; optional Labels; support for "Include" would be nice.

An example configuration file might looks like:

```
Listen Inside 127.0.0.1:1000;
Listen Outside {
    IP 1.2.3.4;
    Port 1000;
    TLS {
        CertFile /path/to/file;
    };
};
ACL default_acl {
    IP 192.168.0.0/24;
    IP 10.0.0.0/24;
};
```

Comment: Are none of the answers from Google, like [libconfig](http://www.hyperrealm.com/libconfig/) adequate? Can you tell us why? Is the sysntax 'set in stone'?

Comment: @gbulmer unfortunately yes, I can't change the syntax. So, libconfig and every other I've found through Google will not work. The syntax was loosely based on BIND's; I've considered ripping libisccfg out of it, but I'm thinking it would be quicker to rewrite.

Comment: okay. Syntax is fixed. So must this parser be very robust, i.e. skip over syntax errors, and continue as best it can, possibly handling multiple errors, or can it give up (with a suitably helpful message) at the first error?

Comment: The other obvious question: is this high performance parsing? You called it a configuration file, so I assumed it wasn't performance critical, and that files were quite small, i.e. less than 100kBytes. Is that reasonable?

Comment: @gbulmer Any response to syntax errors is acceptable, as long as it's consistent. Performance isn't a consideration, as long as it can do 1KB in less than a few seconds it's good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What programming languages are you familiar with? My impression from your question is C.

It looks like like the tokens of your configuration language are regular expressions:

- Listen
- 127.0.0.1:1000
- 1000
- ;
- {
- }
- etc.

Almost all modern programming languages have some form of support for those.

If the implementation is C, I'd probably use flex. It generates a function which will apply a set of regular expressions, put the matched text into a C string, and return the type of that regular expression (just an int, which you choose). The function is a 'lexical analyser' or 'tokeniser'. It chops up streams of characters into handy units that match your needs, one regular expression at a time.

Flex is pretty easy to use. It has several advantages over lex. One is that you can have multiple lexical analysers functions, so if you need to do something odd for an include file, then you could have a second lexical analyser function for that job.

Your language looks simple. Bison/Yacc are very powerful tools, and "with great power comes great responsibility" :-)

I think it is sufficiently simple, that I might just write a parser by hand. It might only be a few functions to handle its structure. A technique that is very straightforward is called recursive descent parser. Have you got a CS degree, or understand this stuff?

Lots of people will (at this stage) tell you to get the '[Dragon Book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201100886)' or one of its newer versions, often because that is what they had at college. The Dragon book is great, but it is like telling someone to read all of Wikipedia to find out about whales. Great if you have the time, and you'll learn a lot.

A reasonable start is the [Wikipedia Recursive Descent parser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser) article. Recursive descent is very popular because it is relatively straightforward to understand. The thing that makes it straightforward is to have a proper grammar which is cast into a form which is easy for recursive descent to parse. Then you literally write a function for every rule, with a simple error handling mechanism (that's why I asked about this). There are probably tools to generate them, but you might find it quicker to just write it. A first cut might take a day, then you'd be in a good position to decide.

A very nifty lex/flex feature is any characters which are not matched, are just echo'd to standard output. So you can see what your regular expressions are matching, and can add them incrementally. When the output 'dries up' everything is being matched.

Pontification alert: IMHO, more C programmers should learn to use flex. It is relatively easy to use, and very powerful for text handling. IMHO lots are put off because they are also told to use yacc/bison which are much more powerful, subtle and complex tools.
end Pontification.

If you need a bit of help with the grammar, please ask. If there is a nice grammar (might not be the case, but so far your examples look okay) then implementation is straightforward.

I found two links to stackoverflow answers which look helpful:

- [Recursive descent parser implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9814528/recursive-descent-parser-implementation)
- [Looking for a tutorial on Recursive Descent Parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2405623/looking-for-a-tutorial-on-recursive-descent-parsing)

Here is an example of using flex.

Flex takes a 'script', and generates a C function called yylex(). This is the input script.

Remember that all of the regular expressions are being matched within that yylex function, so though the script looks weird, it is really an ordinary C function. To tell the caller, which will be your recursive descent parser, what type of regular expression is matched, it returns an integer value that you choose, just like any ordinary C function.

If there is nothing to tell the parser about, like white space, and probably some form of comment, it doesn't return. It 'silently' consumes those characters. If the syntax *needs* to use newline, then that would be recognised as a token, and a suitable token value returned to the parser. It is sometimes easier to let it be more free form, so this example consumes and ignores all white space.

Effectively the yylex function is everything from the first `%%` to the second `%%`. It behaves like a big `switch()` statement.

The regular expressions are like (very exotic) `case:` labels.

The code inside the `{ ... }` is ordinary C. It can contain any C statements, and must be properly nested within the `{ ... }`

The stuff before the first `%%` is the place to put flex definitions, and a few 'instructions' to flex.
The stuff inside `%{ ... %}` is ordinary C, and can include any headers needed by the C in the file, or even define global variables.

The stuff after the second `%%` is ordinary C, with no need for extra syntax, so no `%{ ... %]`.

```
/* scanner for a configuration files */ 
%{ 
    /* Put headers in here */ 
#include <config.h>

%} 
%%
[0-9]+                  { return TOK_NUMBER; } 
[0-9]+"."[0-9]+"."[0-9]+"."[0-9]+":"[0-9]+ { return TOK_IP_PORT; } 
[0-9]+"."[0-9]+"."[0-9]+"."[0-9]+"/"[0-9]+ { return TOK_IP_RANGE; } 
"Listen"                { return TOK_KEYWORD_LISTEN; } 
[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9_]*   { return TOK_IDENTIFIER; }
"{"                     { return TOK_OPEN_BRACE; }
"}"                     { return TOK_CLOSE_BRACE; }
";"                     { return TOK_SEMICOLON; }
[ \t\n]+        /* eat up whitespace, do nothing */ 
.           { fprintf(stderr,  "Unrecognized character: %s\n", yytext ); 
              exit(1); 
            }
%%

/* -------- A simple test ----------- */
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{ 
    int tok;
    yyin = stdin;
    while (tok=yylex()) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%d %s\n", tok, yytext);
    }
}
```

That has a minimal, dummy main, which calls the yylex() function to get the next token 
(enum) value. yytext is the string matched by the regular expression, so main just prints it.

WARNING, this is barely tested, little more than:

```
flex config.l
gcc lex.yy.c -ll
./a.out <tinytest
```

The values are just integers, so an enum in a header:

```
#ifndef _CONFIG_H_
#define _CONFIG_H_

enum TOKENS { 
 TOK_KEYWORD_LISTEN = 256, 
 TOK_IDENTIFIER = 257, 
 TOK_OPEN_BRACE = 258, 
 TOK_CLOSE_BRACE = 259, 
 TOK_SEMICOLON = 260, 
 TOK_IP_PORT = 261, 
 TOK_IP_RANGE = 262, 
 TOK_NUMBER = 263, 
};
#endif _CONFIG_H_
```

In your parser, call yylex when you need the next value. You'll probably wrap yylex in something which copies yytext before handing the token type value back to the parser.

You will need to be comfortable handling memory. If this were a large file, maybe use malloc to allocate space. But for small files, and to make it easy to get started and debug, it might makes sense to write your own 'dumb' allocator. A 'dumb' memory management system, can make debugging much easier. Initially just have a big char array statically allocated and a mymalloc() handing out pieces. I can imagine the configuration data never gets free()'d. Everything can be held in C strings initially, so it is straightforward to debug because the exact sequence of input is in the char array. An improved version might 'stat' a file, and allocates a piece big enough.

How you deal with the actual configuration values is a bit beyond what I can describe. Text strings might be all that is needed, or maybe there is already a mechanism for that. Often there is no need to store the text value of 'Keywords', because the parser has recognised what it means, and the program might convert other values, e.g. IP addresses, into some internal representation.

Comment: Wow; thanks for the detailed write-up! This is the first I've heard of Flex, digging into it now. I have a degree in CIS, so some programming, enough to get through this; just didn't want to reinvent the wheel if there was something simple already available. I've used libconfig before, but the syntax doesn't fit here. If nobody comes up with a silver bullet you've got the Accepted Answer.

Comment: @Chris S - I'm suggesting this route because I think it is very tractable, you seem to have an awkward (set in stone) requirement, you've looked, and several others have looked, but no one has yet suggested a nearer off the shelf solution. It looks like a good fit for your problem. A better fit might be a good library which handles the syntax you need. A handy side benefit of flex is it is a tried and tested tool, with a reasonable number of users, and books and tutorials on how to use it.

Comment: @Chris S - I've added an short flex lexical-analyser definition to show how it might be used with a (simple) C program. It builds. I think it contains most of the basis ideas. It isn't adequately tested, and there are techniques to make it more useful. It can switch-on and off sets of extra regular expressions on the fly. Remember yylex consumes the text of one regular expression at a time (conceptually, they all run in 'parallel', and the longest matching string wins). So if you use yylex to recognise smaller pieces of string, you might lose its ability to identify the type of the next thing.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at [lex and yacc](http://dinosaur.compilertools.net/) (or alternatively, flex and bison)?  It's a little hairy, but we use those to parse files that look exactly like your config file there.  You can define sub-structures using brackets, parse variable-length lists with the same key, etc.

By labels do you mean comments?  You can define your own comment structure, we use '#' to denote a comment line.

It doesn't support includes AFAIK.

Answer (score 0):

Exist C library's to [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) and [YAML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML). They look like what you need.

Comment: JSON and YAML might be similar, but definitely aren't compatible.