# How to convert excel 'AND' ,'OR ' condition to mongo conditions

Tags: excel, mongodb

I have some condition in excel format like this:
`AND(name = 'bob', age < 10)` and it can be nested also.
I want to convert it into mongo format for querying data:
This should be translated into:
Excel condition: `AND(name <> 'bob', age < 10)` 
equivalent mongo Condition: `{$and: [{name: {$eq: 'bob'}},{age: {$lt: 10}}]}`

This query can be nested also like and inside or and OR and or inside and. Can anyone suggest me some method for this.

Nesting Examples: It can be nesting of 'AND' and 'OR' multiple times:
Eg:

1 - `OR(AND(name <> 'bob', age < 10),AND(name <> 'john', age > 40), age = 40)`

Equivalent Mongo Query: `{$or: [{$and: [{name: {$ne: 'bob'}}, {age: {$lt: 10}}]}, {$and: [{name: {$ne: 'john'}}, {age: {$gt: 10}}]}, age: {$eq: 40}]}`

2- `AND(OR(name <> 'bob', age < 10),AND(name <> 'john', age > 40), age = 40)`

Equivalent Mongo Query: `{$and: [{$or: [{name: {$ne: 'bob'}}, {age: {$lt: 10}}]}, {$or: [{name: {$ne: 'john'}}, {age: {$gt: 40}}]}, age: {$eq: 40}]}`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you add an example of the nesting that you're talking about? That feels like it's the crux of your question & it's hard to answer without seeing it

Comment: Hi @willis.. Please have a look. I have edited it..

Comment: So, rephrasing the question a little bit -- you're trying to write a simple parser to transform a string excel condition into a mongo query?

Comment: yes.. I want to convert them

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9814528/recursive-descent-parser-implementation has details about how one would tackle a problem like this.